# Container without order

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme, poetry, computer-science

> You try to see doubly well
> But I'm not for locations
> You try to slither in through
> But I'm not for foreign words
>
> Don't worry, I'm here to store
> You just need a key to find
> The time admits it's no chore
> The log; from how I'm designed

What am I?